# How to make a pure JS anology of lodash throttle leading

Tags: javascript, lodash

Can anyone tell what is the way of making pure JS anology of please:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', _.throttle(callback, 500, { leading: true, trailing: false}));
```

Comment: Look at lodashs source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
function throttle(func, wait, options) {
  var context, args, result;
  var timeout = null;
  var previous = 0;
  if (!options) options = {};
  var later = function() {
    previous = options.leading === false ? 0 : Date.now();
    timeout = null;
    result = func.apply(context, args);
    if (!timeout) context = args = null;
  };
  return function() {
    var now = Date.now();
    if (!previous && options.leading === false) previous = now;
    var remaining = wait - (now - previous);
    context = this;
    args = arguments;
    if (remaining <= 0 || remaining > wait) {
      if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
      }
      previous = now;
      result = func.apply(context, args);
      if (!timeout) context = args = null;
    } else if (!timeout && options.trailing !== false) {
      timeout = setTimeout(later, remaining);
    }
    return result;
  };
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', throttle(callback, 500, { leading: true, trailing: false}));
```

Comment: Jiby! thanks man, but why this isn't working? check my example here please and tell me what am I doing wrong: https://jsfiddle.net/3pk1op97/

Comment: @zocihi because you are adding a scroll listener, but your page is not long enough to have scroll to do scroll, try adding `.target { height: 1000px }` as css to add scroll to the page, you can see https://jsfiddle.net/3pk1op97/4/, i just added the css

Comment: OMG man! I'm noobie in all of this, but this is craaaaazy-cool! xD THANKS!

Answer (score -1):

Here is the source : `https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/throttle.js`

```
function throttle(func, wait, options) {
  let leading = true
  let trailing = true

  if (typeof func != 'function') {
    throw new TypeError('Expected a function')
  }
  if (isObject(options)) {
    leading = 'leading' in options ? !!options.leading : leading
    trailing = 'trailing' in options ? !!options.trailing : trailing
  }
  return debounce(func, wait, {
    'leading': leading,
    'maxWait': wait,
    'trailing': trailing
  })
}
```

refer debounce from here - `https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/debounce.js`

Comment: so I need debounce to be imported before? and before that I need isObject.js and root.js to be imported too? how can I make this stand alone without all this unnecessary things?

Comment: in that case just refer this, standalone version of throttle,
`https://github.com/niksy/throttle-debounce/blob/master/throttle.js`